# PHP Argument type (options)

Tags: php, list, arguments

I am looking to create functions which have values I can select when calling them later.
IE:

```
function doThisThing(param1, param2)
{ do... something ...; }
```

however when I call it I would like the params to intelisense a list of available options.

While I have a lot of experience in various languages, I do not know how to create this functionality.

Comment: That sounds like a function of the editor you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using PHP Storm. Is that something you are a familiar with? Enough to help make said adjustment?